# How to sort collection in java based on bean class propery which is String type

Tags: java, collections

I want to sort List which contains MyBean object based on name propery without touching MyBean class

I have a bean class like

```
public class MyBean
{
    private String name, city;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCity(String city)
    {
      this.city= city;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
      return name;
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
      return city;
    }

}
```

I have another class like,

```
public class MyCollection
{
    p s v main(String args[])
    {
       MyBean bean1 = new MyBean();
       MyBean bean2 = new MyBean();

       bean1.setName("arun");
       bean1.setCity("xyz");

       bean2.setName("raju");
       bean2.setCity("abc");

       bean2.setName("bharani");
       bean2.setCity("abcfr");       

       ArrayList list = new ArrayList():
       list.add(bean1);
       list.add(bean2);
    }

}
```

After sorting it should print list names like
arun
bharani
raju

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [lamda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) from Java 8 along with [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort) like that

```
Collections.sort(list, (MyBean b1, MyBean b2) -> b1.getName().compareTo(b2.getName()));
```

Much cleaner! :)

Comment: Even better :             Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(MyBean::getName));

Comment: Like most other answers, both the first and the second syntax throw an exception if `b1` or `b2` is `null`, or if `b1.getName()` is `null`. I'm yet to find a syntactic sugar for short comparisons in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Use Comparator or Comparable to achieve sort based on the bean property.

if you prefer Comparator use this code.

```
   Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyBean >() {
        @Override public int compare(MyBean b1, MyBean b2) {
            return b1.name.compareTo(b2.name);
        }

    });
```

or use Comparable in this way

```
   public class MyBean  implements Comparable<MyBean> {
        private String name, city;    
        // Add/generate getters/setters
         public int compareTo(MyBean  other) {
             return name.compareTo(other.name);
         }    
    }

   List<MyBean> list= new ArrayList<MyBean>();
   Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort) with  [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
  Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<MyBean>(){
     @Override
     public int compare(MyBean myBean1, MyBean myBean2) {
        return myBean1.getName().compareTo(myBean2.getName());
     }
  }
```